# simple Vuforia to HoloLens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zxing, vuforia, hololens

I am trying to get a simple Vuforia image from HoloLens to a function that converts QRCodes to text (via ZXing). I have imported the ZXing library and upon reading over similar implementations have found that the below implementation is in it's simplest form.

It is actually quite simple, the steps are

1. start by setting up the barcode object
2. initialize the camera
3. send the QRcode's text value to console

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System;
   using System.Collections;
   using UnityEngine.UI;
   using Vuforia;

   using ZXing;

   public class HelloWorldV2 : MonoBehaviour
   {
   private bool cameraInitialized;

   private BarcodeReader barReader;

   void Start()
   {
       GameObject sometext = GameObject.Find("Text");
       Text txt = sometext.GetComponent<Text>();

       txt.text = "Right before BarReader";
       barReader = new BarcodeReader();
       txt.text = "Right after BarReader"; //NEVER GETS HERE!

       StartCoroutine(InitializeCamera());
   }

   private IEnumerator InitializeCamera()
   {
       // Waiting a little seem to avoid the Vuforia's crashes.
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.25f);

       var isFrameFormatSet = CameraDevice.Instance.SetFrameFormat(Vuforia.Image.PIXEL_FORMAT.RGB888, true);
       Debug.Log(String.Format("FormatSet : {0}", isFrameFormatSet));

       // Force autofocus.
       var isAutoFocus = CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode(CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO);
       if (!isAutoFocus)
       {
           CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode(CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_NORMAL);
       }
       Debug.Log(String.Format("AutoFocus : {0}", isAutoFocus));
       cameraInitialized = true;
   }

   private void Update()
   {
       if (cameraInitialized)
       {
           try
           {
               var cameraFeed = CameraDevice.Instance.GetCameraImage(Vuforia.Image.PIXEL_FORMAT.RGB888);
               if (cameraFeed == null)
               {
                   return;
               }
               var data = barReader.Decode(cameraFeed.Pixels, cameraFeed.BufferWidth, cameraFeed.BufferHeight, RGBLuminanceSource.BitmapFormat.RGB24);
               if (data != null)
               {
                   // QRCode detected.
                   Debug.Log(data.Text);
               }
               else
               {
                   Debug.Log("No QR code detected !");
               }
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Debug.LogError(e.Message);
           }
       }
   }
   }
   ```

So the issue occurs simply on the constructor call to `BarcodeReader()`. Which I'm not sure how this would be happening. Why would a simple constructor call fail?

The only other hint I'm getting from a debug session is the following:

```
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, 
Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of 
its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match 
the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
    at ZXing.BarcodeReader..ctor()
    at HelloWorldV2.Start()
```

Can someone replicate the issue through VisualStudio's Emulator? (Note, this works in Unity when replacing the FrameFormats to grayscale.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to build a working solution for scanning QR codes with ZXing on HoloLens based on this blog post:

https://mtaulty.com/2016/12/28/windows-10-uwp-qr-code-scanning-with-zxing-and-hololens/

Answer (score 1):

That's because you used the wrong dll file (which is not supported on hololens). Try the winmd file in ZXing.net